# JavaScript Syntaxt conditional syntaxt ? and

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Often finding the conditional syntax like array followed by "?" and "." and element, example - `edges[0]?.node`. How to interpret the following code?

```
export default function Index({ allPosts: { edges }, preview }) {
  const heroPost = edges[0]?.node;
  const morePosts = edges.slice(1);
  ....// rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: Its called optional chaining https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the `optional chaining` operator (?.) which enables you to read the value of a property located deep inside a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid in each reference protecting you from getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

This operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is considered nullish (which means null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined (hence, not throwing an exception).

```js
const person = {
  name: 'John',
  dog: {
    name: 'cc'
  }
};

const dogName = person.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);

console.log(person.cat?.name?.prop); // undefined instead of throwing an error
```